# How to bypass whitelist based internet censorship

Tags: firewall, routing

How can we bypass internet censorship in Iran

In Iran government blocked internet access to global and we can only access servers that hosted in Iran datacenters.

I think they used whitelisting technique to block internet

can we bypass it ?

we can't use vpns because access to outside servers are blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first general way is to find a flaw in the whitelist (e.g. find a server which is whitelisted but you can control that system and go further through it).

For instance, if in some local datacenter traffic is not filtered as hard as home traffic and outside servers are accessible from that datacenter, you can access them by installing a proxy or a VPN in that datacenter. It is enough for just one remote VPS to be accessible; then you can build a path through it.

The second way is to hide traffic inside innocent looking and non-blocked protocols; that is called a *steganography*. For example, the `iodine` software allows to build a VPN over the DNS. You have to manage to install a server outside as one endpoint and use a local client inside as other endpoint. The downside of such solution is that it has notoriously low performance (high delays and low throughput).

---

While I deeply understand your situation (in the Russia, my homeland, the Internet is being censored too), and I am willing to share my knowledge to help, I am afraid the way the question is asked it is unsuitable for this site. We are solving concrete business problems. Without clear problem statement and defined end state, we will not be able to help.